# Non-time level inside a time dimension

Tags: mondrian

I have a time dimension defined something like the following:

```
<Dimension name="optin" type="TimeDimension">
  <Hierarchy name="optin" hasAll="true" allMemberName="all optin" primaryKey="profile_id">
    <Table schema="schema1" name="profiles"/>
    <Level name="optin_year" column="optin_year" uniqueMembers="false" type="Numeric" levelType="TimeYears"/>
    <Level name="optin_quarter" column="optin_quarter" uniqueMembers="false" type="Numeric" levelType="TimeQuarters"/>
    <Level name="optin_month" column="optin_month" uniqueMembers="false" type="Numeric" levelType="TimeMonths"/>
    <Level name="optin_day_in_month" column="optin_day_in_month" uniqueMembers="false" type="Numeric" levelType="TimeDays"/>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

This works well for segmenting on various date parts (year, quarter,
month, day).  However, I want to also be able to report the number of
profiles which have the `optin` field filled in (non-NULL).  For
non-time dimensions adding this hierarchy to the above dimension
works:

```
<Hierarchy name="defined" hasAll="true" allMemberName="all optin" primaryKey="profile_id">
  <Table schema="schema1" name="profiles"/>
  <Level name="defined" uniqueMembers="true" type="Boolean">
    <KeyExpression>
      <SQL>optin_day_in_month IS NOT NULL</SQL>
    </KeyExpression>
  </Level>
</Hierarchy>
```

However, when I add this to a time dimension I get the following
exception from Mondrian:

```
Level '[optin.defined].[defined]' belongs to a time hierarchy, so
its level-type must be 'Years', 'Quarters', 'Months', 'Weeks' or
'Days'.
```

I can place the hierarchy `defined` into a separate dimension, but
then I end up with two non-orthogonal dimensions which don't make any
sense to segment on simultaneously.  These really *are* two
hierarchies within the same dimension.  I can also turn the `optin`
dimension into a non-time dimension but then I lose the ability to
use time series functions (`PARALLELPERIOD`, `YTD`, etc.).

What's the best way to achieve what I want--to be able to segment on a
date field parts and on whether or not it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

> Level '[optin.defined].[defined]' belongs to a time hierarchy, so
>   its level-type must be 'Years', 'Quarters', 'Months', 'Weeks' or
>   'Days'.

The error tells you, that it is impossible to have "non-time based" (`Regular`) levels within time dimension (`TimeDimension`):

```
<Dimension name="optin" type="TimeDimension">
   ...
   <Level name="defined" uniqueMembers="true" type="Boolean">
```

A level of the Regular type can be used only with `StandardDimension`.

> What's the best way to achieve what I want--to be able to segment on a
>   date field parts and on whether or not it's empty?

I think you don't use the time dimension properly. Standard way is to have time dimension as follows:

- **DWH:** Preloaded time data in you data warehouse (records for every day from, let say, 1900-01-01 to 2099-12-31) - table `dim_time` with `date_key` (e.g. `20150123`)
- **OLAP schema:** Proper time dimension `<Dimension name="Time" type="TimeDimension">` which contains `levels` for "years / quarters / months / weeks / days". Similar to the one you have but this way it contains all days. With `primary_key` attribute pointing to `date_key`.

Next step is to adjust the `optin` (profile):

- **DWH:** `optin` row data + optin_date_key (which can be null or have value)
- **OLAP schema:** Create cube for `profile` with, use time dimension created before with `foreign_key` pointing to `optin_date_key`. And measure which sums all profiles with non-null `optin_date_key` values.

Sample OLAP code for profile cube:

```
<DimensionUsage source="Time" name="Time" caption="Profile Date" visible="true" foreignKey="optin_date_key" highCardinality="false">
</DimensionUsage>
<Measure name="#Profiles" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
  <MeasureExpression>
    <SQL dialect="generic">
        <![CDATA[optin_date_key]]>
    </SQL>
  </MeasureExpression>
</Measure>
```

This way you should be able to report the number of profiles which have the `optin` field filled in (non-NULL).

What more you can do is using this cube within a virtual cube to with join other measures.